# Connecting a Raspberry Pi 3 to Intel IoT Analytics

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, windows-iot, internet

I would like to connect a Raspberry Pi 3 to Intel IoT Analytics.Is.

Is it even possible? If it is possible, how can I do that? I have came across many tutorials on connecting Intel Edison or Galileo boards to Intel IoT Analytic. Nevertheless I would like to connect my Raspberry Pi 3 to IoT Analytics to make something like this [Smart Energy Monitoring and Control System](https://www.hackster.io/taifur/smart-energy-monitoring-control-system-edison-inside-04bc06?ref=part&ref_id=8232&offset=35).

Comment: As fare as I could find out, there are some commandline tools. They interact with the portal. You can open an account and define a device but then you need some confirmation from the device. Try to find the source of the tools for this plattform. Otherwise there a lots of other IoT portals around. Like https://thingspeak.com/ you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation I've been able to find on the platform, the Intel IoT Analytic platform is specific to the Intel IoT products. Since the hardware is incompatible, it's unlikely you'll be able to make the platform work with the RPi.